# Aparecer table após preenchimento de campos e botão pressionado

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Possuo a seguinte table:

```
 <table width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-striped" id="empenho_solicitante">  
    <thead>
        <tr>       
             <th>Empenho</th>
             <th>Programatica</th>
             <th>Conta Desp.</th>
             <th>Credor</th>
             <th>Valor</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
       <?php  
            while ($linha = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado))
            {
            ?>
                 <tr class="odd gradeA">
                 <td align = "right"> <?php echo $linha["num_empenho"]; ?> </td>
                 <td align = "center"><?php echo $linha["programatica"];?> </td>
                 <td align = "center"> <?php echo $linha["conta_desp"]; ?> </td>
                 <td align="left"><?php echo $linha["nome_fornecedor"]; ?> </td>
                 <td align = "right"> <?php echo 
                        number_format($linha["valor_empenhado"], 2, ',', '.'); 
                        $total +=  $linha["valor_empenhado"]; ?> </td>
                 </tr>
            <?php                                       
            }
            ?>                                        
            <td colspan="4" align = "middle"> <?php echo "Valor empenhado para este solicitante no período:" ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo number_format($total, 2, ',', '.'); ?> </td>                                   
      </tbody>
</table>
```

E também tenho um select, gostaria que eles somente aparecessem após o preenchimento de 4 campos e um botão "consultar" fosse pressionado, segue o form com esses elementos:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    Início do período:
    <input type="text" id="calendarioIni" name="dataInicio">
    Fim do período:
    <input type="text" id="calendarioFim" name="dataFim">
    <br><br><br>
    <span class="IWLABEL11CSS" id="IWLABEL7">Órgão: </span>
    <select name="Distrito" size="1" width="180" class="COMBODISTCSS" id="COMBOFAB" tabindex="1">
        <option value="01">Gabinete do Prefeito</option>
        <option value="02">Coordenadoria de Governo e Comunicação Social</option>
        <option value="03">Secertaria Municipal de Planejamento</option>
        <option value="04">Procuradoria Jurídica</option>
        <option value="05">Ouvidoria Municipal</option>
        <option value="06">Secretaria Municipal de Administração</option>
        <option value="07">Secretaria Municipal da Fazenda</option>
        <option value="08">Auditoria Interna</option>
        <option value="09">Secretaria Municipal de Obras</option>
        <option value="10">Secretaria Municipal de Desenvolvimento Urbano e Meio Ambiente</option>
        ...
        </select>

    <span class="IWLABEL11CSS" id="IWLABEL7">Unidade: </span>
    <select name="Concelho" size="1" width="195" class="COMBOCONCCSS" id="COMBOCID" tabindex="1">
         <option data-distrito="01" value="01">Gabinete do Prefeito</option>
         <option data-distrito="01" value="02">Departamento de Assuntos Institucionais</option>
         <option data-distrito="02" value="03">Gabinete da Coordenadoria de Governo e Comunicação Social</option>
         <option data-distrito="02" value="04">Departamento de Comunicação Social</option>
          <option data-distrito="02" value="05">Administração Distrital de Ipoema</option>
         <option data-distrito="02" value="06">Administração Distrital de Senhora do Carmo</option>
         <option data-distrito="03" value="07">Gabinete da Secretaria Municipal de Planejamento</option>
         <option data-distrito="03" value="08">Departamento de Orçamento Municipal</option>
         <option data-distrito="03" value="09">Departamento de Estudos e Avaliação</option>
         ...
    </select>
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" id="consultar" value="Consultar" />
    <br><br><br>

     <?php if(isset($_POST['dataInicio']) && isset($_POST['dataFim']))
           {
                  $dataIni = $_POST['dataInicio'];
                  $dataIni = str_replace("/", "-",$dataIni);
                  $dataIni = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dataIni));
                  $dataFim = $_POST['dataFim'];
                  $dataFim = str_replace("/", "-",$dataFim);
                  $dataFim = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dataFim));
                  $cod_orgao = $_POST['Distrito'];
                  $cod_unidade = $_POST['Concelho'];
                  echo $dataIni."<br>";//Teste para verificar o valor nas variáveis
                  echo $dataFim."<br>";
                  echo $cod_orgao."<br>";
                  echo $cod_unidade."<br>";
           } 
           ?>                                    
</form>
```

Comment: Se a sua tabela será preenchida com dados vindos do servidor por consequência da consulta feita no form, você precisará fazer um post ajax e popular a tabela por javascript ou um post simples que resultaria em um "refresh" da página.

Comment: eu já estou fazendo esse post simples com o refresh da página, mas gostaria que a tabela só aparecesse mediate o pressionamento do botão "consultar" .

Comment: Você pode retornar uma variável só para isso ou adicionar um if antes da tabela verificando se a $resultado possui algum valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente verificar se a página é o resultado de um post.

```
<?
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
?>
    <table width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-striped" id="empenho_solicitante">  
<thead>
    <tr>       
        <th>Empenho</th>
        <th>Programatica</th>
        <th>Conta Desp.</th>
        <th>Credor</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php  
    while ($linha = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado))
    {
    ?>
        <tr class="odd gradeA">
        <td align = "right"> <?php echo $linha["num_empenho"]; ?> </td>
        <td align = "center"><?php echo $linha["programatica"];?> </td>
        <td align = "center"> <?php echo $linha["conta_desp"]; ?> </td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $linha["nome_fornecedor"]; ?> </td>
        <td align = "right"> <?php echo 
            number_format($linha["valor_empenhado"], 2, ',', '.'); 
            $total +=  $linha["valor_empenhado"]; ?> </td>
        </tr>
    <?php                                       
    }
    ?>                                        
    <td colspan="4" align = "middle"> <?php echo "Valor empenhado para este solicitante no período:" ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo number_format($total, 2, ',', '.'); ?> </td>                                   
</tbody>
</table>
<? } ?>
```